# How to run grunt build in order to deploy the web application with bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: git, deployment, gruntjs, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to generate the web application in production mode (running grunt build) and push the generated files and folders from the **dist/** folder on my webhost with bitbucket pipelines via git ftp.

**Bitbucket web application structure**

```
app[dir]
tests[dir]
.gitignore
Gruntfile.js
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
bower.json
package.json
...
```

**gitignore**

```
/node_modules
/dist
/.tmp
/.sass-cache
/bower_components

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
Icon?
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
log
node_modules
node

# Personal application yamls #
##############################
*bitbucket-pipelines.yml
src/main/resources/static/js/vendor
application-cat.yml
.tern-project
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
.idea/workspace.xml
```

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: node:4.6.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      script: 
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
        - npm install
        - npm install -g grunt-cli
        - npm install -g grunt@0.4.5
        - npm install -g bower
        - bower install  --allow-root
        - grunt build
        - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://myDomain.com/public_html/folder/
```

**Notice**

If I run locally "grunt build" it will generate a folder in my root application name: **dist** (witch is OK !!).
If I run the bitbucket.pipelines.yml script (all with success), it will not generate any **dist** folder (witch is NOT OK !!).

**Conclusion**

> I ended up with pushing all repository on my webhost because I can't target any **dist** folder. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: @Gowri hello, no...and I haven't search for other solution from then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use **.git-ftp-include** file to include the untracked files. if grunt build generates the **build** folder. Then we need to add the following in .git-ftp-include to force the build folder in sync process.

```
!build/
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, I will check asap

Comment: @Gowri it is the appropriate way to fix the dist folder availability issue?